# "relax" or "relaxing"? -- I hope you are having some rest and relaxing at the end of the year

Tags: sentence-construction, idioms, gerunds, present-continuous, nominalization

I am sending someone a message, and I started with this:

> Good day. I hope you are having some rest and **relaxing** at the end of the year.

is it correct to use the *-ing* in the *relaxing* word?

Comment: (Informal) _Hi Marco. I hope you are having a relaxing time throughout the festive holidays._   (Formal) _Dear Mr Dinatsoli. I hope you are..._   Unless you are from Australia, I wouldn't start any message with, 'Good day.' And even then, not!

Answer (score 1):

You need the noun, which is relaxation. So this would be grammatical.

> I hope you are having some rest and relaxation.

Ways you can use relaxing grammatically:

> The cat is relaxing.
>
> The relaxing cat is over there.
>
> The holiday was relaxing.

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

Here is the same situation in a shorter sentence:

> I hope you are relaxing.

The meaning is the same as:

> I hope that you are relaxing.

**You are relaxing** is a subordinate clause, with **relax** in the present progressive tense.

---

In the original sentence, notice that **relaxing** is not an object of **having**. It would not make sense to say:

> I hope you are having some relaxing.

so, a reader just won't interpret the sentence that way. That's not a problem.

---

However, **having some rest** isn't the ordinary way to say this concept. It's grammatical and it's not wrong, but normally one says **getting some rest**. So a more ordinary-sounding way to say it would be:

> I hope you are getting some rest and relaxing at the end of the year.

The phrase **rest and relaxation** is even more familiar. Making both **r-** words into nouns, both objects of **getting**, sounds pleasing to the ear. So, a nicer way to say it is:

> I hope you are getting some rest and relaxation at the end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

I think the use of "relaxing" is unnecessary in the sentence, as to rest and to relax are synonyms. You can say I hope you are having/taking some rest or relaxing at the end of the year.